# Should it be find instead found in Ed sheeran's song?

Tags: verbs

Ed Sheeran's song 'Thinking out loud' has a line

> Maybe we found love right where we are

I think it should be

> Maybe we find love right where we are

Comment: Hi, beginner. Do you just mean that you think "we" should not be capitalized? In which case, I feel like it was just a typo because it appears as lowercase on [other lyric websites](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/edsheeran/thinkingoutloud.html).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Hi, Its not about "we", I am talking about verb, why did he use "found" instead "find"

Comment: I think he wants to rhyme it with "out" and "loud".

Comment: @user178049 ,haha yeah may be.

Comment: @beginner I think you should know that lyricists don't follow grammar rules. They sometimes intentionally cut down words because they need a good syllabic count in the song.

Comment: @user178049 I knew that, I just wanted to be sure that it is grammarly incorrect

Comment: Heh, so silly of me. I must have been zoning out. I had read and re-read the sentences several times and hadn't noticed the difference in the verb. I would agree that perhaps "Maybe we have found..." would be better, but as user178049 has mentioned...lyrics. Meanwhile, I personally would not choose simple present to replace it.

Comment: Plus, using past tense does convey a deeper sense of certainty, which, a song crooner may want to convey when wooing someone with his song. Like, "Hey, we found it."

Answer (score 1):

I believe, since this song was inspired by his girlfriend at the time, he was specifically talking about the love they had for each other, at that time. Since that love started at a previous point in time, I believe he meant to use "found", to fit the past tense.

If he had instead, used the word find, he would be making a philosophical statement about the love and his on-going thoughts, rather than his concrete assessment regarding their having found love, right where they were.